# Delete everything before a pattern, and removing symbol

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

I have over 300 lines containing text from Jenkins plugins in this pattern:

```
Server Sent Events (SSE) Gateway Plugin (sse-gateway): 1.24
Common API for Blue Ocean (blueocean-commons): 1.24.4
Handy Uri Templates 2.x API Plugin (handy-uri-templates-2-api): 2.1.8-1.0
Durable Task Plugin (durable-task): 1.35
Git Pipeline for Blue Ocean (blueocean-git-pipeline): 1.24.0
REST API for Blue Ocean (blueocean-rest): 1.24.4
Terraform Plugin (terraform): 1.0.10
GIT server Plugin (git-server): 1.9
Web for Blue Ocean (blueocean-web): 1.24.0
Bitbucket Pipeline for Blue Ocean (blueocean-bitbucket-pipeline): 1.24.0
```

I'm looking for a way to trim out the unnecessary text, using tools like `sed` or `awk` for example, and have a result like so:

```
- plugin-util-api:1.7.0
- blueocean-pipeline-api-impl:1.24.0
- credentials-binding:1.24
- Pipelineworkflow-aggregator:2.6
- hashicorp-vault-plugin:3.6.1
- matrix-project:1.18
- blueocean-display-url:2.4.1
- structs:1.21
```

Comment: Can you supply what the output for the example you supplied would look like I don't see the names or numbers in your output example in your input example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```bsh
$ sed 's/^.*(\([^()]*\)): \(.*\)$/- \1:\2/' file
- sse-gateway:1.24
- blueocean-commons:1.24.4
- handy-uri-templates-2-api:2.1.8-1.0
- durable-task:1.35
- blueocean-git-pipeline:1.24.0
- blueocean-rest:1.24.4
- terraform:1.0.10
- git-server:1.9
- blueocean-web:1.24.0
- blueocean-bitbucket-pipeline:1.24.0
```

Comment: @sschrodigerscatcuriosity. thanks

Comment: Same result but perhaps more readable: `sed 's/.*(/- /; s/): /:/'`

Comment: @glennjackman Excellent, you should make it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

An `gawk` solution:

```
awk -F'): ' -v OFS=':' '{ sub(/.*\(/, "", $1); print " - "$1,$2 }' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F'[(): ]+' '{print "-", $(NF-1)":"$NF}' file
- sse-gateway:1.24
- blueocean-commons:1.24.4
- handy-uri-templates-2-api:2.1.8-1.0
- durable-task:1.35
- blueocean-git-pipeline:1.24.0
- blueocean-rest:1.24.4
- terraform:1.0.10
- git-server:1.9
- blueocean-web:1.24.0
- blueocean-bitbucket-pipeline:1.24.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Two substitutions on each line:

1. Replace everything up to and including the last `(` with a dash and a space.
2. Replace the `):` followed by a space with a dash.

```
$ sed 's/.*(/- /; s/): /-/' file
- sse-gateway-1.24
- blueocean-commons-1.24.4
- handy-uri-templates-2-api-2.1.8-1.0
- durable-task-1.35
- blueocean-git-pipeline-1.24.0
- blueocean-rest-1.24.4
- terraform-1.0.10
- git-server-1.9
- blueocean-web-1.24.0
- blueocean-bitbucket-pipeline-1.24.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F ')' '
{
  sub(/.*\(/, " - ", $(NF-1))
  print $(NF-1) $(NF)
}
' file
```